# How can I remove standard markers and leave only my own markers in Google map

Tags: google-maps, angular-google-maps

[The picture shows what I want to delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zSuS.jpg)

Comment: Your question is a duplicate + it is too broad.

Answer (score -2):

We can use stylers property for Google Map.

Generator style for Google Map : https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Comment: Please avoid link-only answers as the page content you refer to might change or become unavailable.